# How easy is it to hide adding a file to a git repository

Tags: integrity, git

Here's the scenario...

I have a git repository on a server that may have been compromised. My development team say that they can trust the files in the directory that houses the git repository because all commits (diffs) and new files being added to the repository are checked and signed off by the repository 'owner' and any new files would show as new to the local version when a status or pull is made.

However I believe that if a person has compromised the server on which the git repository is housed, there must be some way to add a file to that repository and cover it up so that when a developer does their next pull, the new file doesn't show up in their git status. Is this the case?

Comment: (I don't really know but am making an educated guess).  I suspect if you can create a new file with the same hash as an existing file you could replace the existing file with the new file and git would not be the wiser.  This would be really difficult to achieve.

Comment: AFAIK the commit history log is not signed, so could you edit the log to make it look like that file was in the initial commit (or any arbitrary commit)?

Comment: So I've not checked this personally to be certain, but it looks like git-rebase may be usuable to modify commit logs http://stackoverflow.com/a/4110978/537897 .  also the identities that git stores aren't checked server side, anyone with access to the repository can call themselves anything they like when they commit (again AFAIK)

Comment: @emory "I suspect if you can create a new file with the same hash" can two files have the same hash and have different contents at the same time?

Comment: @Ulkoma Yes, it's called a [Collision Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) and it's a very common method for breaking hash functions.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Oh yes, I remember that now but what are the chances that a malicious file's hash matches a good file' hash? also would not it be easy to detect that by comparing the hashes of a different hashing function?

Comment: @Ulkoma Yup, both good points. I didn't say that collision attacks are easy to pull off, just that they're possible :P ... and that attackers do use them to good effect.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth yes, that is the word I was looking for.  Is it really common? It seems extraordinarily difficult.

Comment: @emory I can't say myself how common collision attacks are "in the wild", but they are the main reason that MD5 and SHA1 are retired. According to `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5` and `en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1` you can find a collision pair for MD5 with 2^18 computations, which runs in under a second on a normal computer, and for SHA1 in ~2^60 computations which is currently intractable but scary enough to make people move off SHA1.

Answer (score 3):

Your developers are correct in that any changes to the repository will be reflected by a new commit. Previous commits cannot be modified without all developers being notified of a serious conflict when updating from the remote repository.

That said, it would be trivial for an attacker to add a new commit to the repository that would automatically be downloaded and applied to developers' local repositories when pulling from the server. I find it extremely implausible that *all* commits to the repository are manually reviewed unless this is a very infrequently-used project. Even if they are reviewed, a motivated attacker could make an innocuous-looking change that has security implications. For example, in 2003, an unknown person added a commit to the Linux kernel [that contained a root escalation vulnerability](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/felten/the-linux-backdoor-attempt-of-2003/). This was back when Linux was using CVS, but the only real protection git has against this sort of attack is gpg-signed commits.

Unless you're using strong cryptographic signatures to protect your commits, there's no way to truly know whether or not a third party modified your repository without doing a full audit of all commits *by the developer that supposedly authored them* since the date of server compromise. This is the only way to truly ensure that an attacker didn't forge a commit by one of your developers.

It's up to you to determine whether or not the risk of the attacker having done this is worth the effort involved in trying to uncover it. If you're a small company making software that doesn't store, protect, or access sensitive data and this looks like a typical drive-by compromise to turn your server into a spam host, I probably wouldn't bother. If you process large quantities of money, I probably would.

Now would also be a good time to ensure that you aren't storing any credentials inside your repository. Things like database passwords, API keys to other services, TLS keys, and cryptographic secrets used for session cookie authentication should never be stored alongside your source code, and you should consider any that have been to be compromised and require rotation.

Comment: This was almost certainly my feeling. The check for authentication credentials has been made. I was interested whether commits could actually been 'hidden' though rather than showing up in developer pulls and not noticed/checked or ignored.

Comment: No, the design of git does not allow that as a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Building on what has been said, reading commit logs is everything however there are ways to trick the end user and having them download files that are not obvious to them.

One way is to add files to the git object database directly instead of the repo (so using `git hash-object` command instead of the normal `git add`). That way they don't appear when you type a list command, so it won't be obvious that they are pulled down.

```
$ echo 'version 1' > test.txt
$ git hash-object -w test.txt
83baae61804e65cc73a7201a7252750c76066a30
```

Your database contains the new content:

```
$ find .git/objects -type f
.git/objects/83/baae61804e65cc73a7201a7252750c76066a30
```

I have seen projects use this method to hide secrets and credentials which is not secure and is simply security by obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

> ...because all commits (diffs) and new files being added to the repository are checked and signed off by the repository 'owner'...

It's important to remember that Git does *not* store diffs of any kind. Every commit contains a complete set of all the files for that commit. Commands such as `git diff` and `git log -p` generate diffs on the fly from the complete files in the commits they are comparing.

> ...and any new files would show as new to the local version when a status or pull is made.

New files will *not* show up when you run `git status` or `git pull` (or `git fetch` followed by `git rebase`, which is the equivalent of `git pull`). So if you're relying on just that, you won't get any indications that new files have been added; they will just quietly appear in your working copy.

For any commit *with only one parent,* you can use `git log --stat` to see the entire list of new and changed files, but it doesn't distinguish between the two, and newly introduced files (or files where it would be suspicious if they are changed) can easily get lost in commits that affect a lot of files. For single-parent commits `git log --patch` will distinguish new files from changed ones, but there it's even easier to miss new files in a commit that affects a lot of files, or even just a lot of lines in a few files.

Unfortunately, this all breaks down if you have commits with more than one parent, i.e. merge commits, in your repo. `git log --patch` and even `git diff` do some suppression of information that people don't normally want to see about a merge, and this includes files newly introduced in merge commits (or at least did so in the past--I myself avoid merge commits now). In particular, I've seen it completely suppressing information about new files added in the "merge" commit itself (i.e., existing in neither parent commit, which doesn't normally happen when doing a merge); in the most egregious example *most of the files in the repo* (hundreds of them) were somehow added in a merge commit and it took me ages to figure out where they came from. (They definitely did not show up in `git log --stat`.)

If you are interested in reliably being able to review exactly what is being changed in your repo (including new file additions), my suggestion is that you avoid merge commits or anything else that can result in a commit having more than one parent. Then you can use `git log --stat` and `git log --patch` and know you're looking at the exact and complete changes introduced by that commit.